Authorization-code error Azureauth R package
I am running a R script on rstudio ide of posit workbench which hosted on Azure VM RHEL 8 Linux server. I am trying to connect to azure application using Azureauth R package using Authorization-code method. When I run the script, I get local host refused to connect but the same Works for device-code method of the Azureauth R package.
The below is R code which I have tried to connect azure application.
R Script -
library(AzureAuth) 
redirect <- "http://localhost:1410" token <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token( "My_Resource", 
"My_Tenant_ID", 
"My_App_ID", 
use_cache = FALSE, 
auth_type = "authorization_code", authorize_args=list(redirect_uri=redirect) )


Error - localhost refused to connect**

But same code works via device-code method of azureauth r package
auth_type = "device_code"

I tried to open the new popped browser URL which gives out localhost refused to connect error via a Linux terminal command curl pop_browser_url and this is authenticating without any error .
Code with device code method works -
library(AzureAuth)
redirect <- "http://localhost:1410" token <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token( "My_Resource",
"My_Tenant_ID",
"My_App_ID",
use_cache = FALSE,
auth_type = "device_code", authorize_args=list(redirect_uri=redirect) )

Can you share your device_code folw code in the question?

Check this Doc to fix the issue.

Can you this GitHub repo for Authorization_code flow.

I successfully retrieved the access token from Azure AD using Authorization_code flow with AzureAuth package in R.
I added the below URL in the Azure AD app's redirect URI under Web as shown below.
http://localhost:1410


Code  :
library(AzureAuth)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

redirect <- "http://localhost:1410"    
resource <- "https://graph.microsoft.com"  
tenant_id <- "<tenantID>" 
app_id <- "<appID>" 

token <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token(
  resource = resource,
  tenant = tenant_id,
  app = app_id,
  use_cache = FALSE,  
  auth_type = "authorization_code",
  authorize_args = list(redirect_uri = redirect)
)

print(token)

cat("Access Token: ", token$credentials$access_token, "\n")

Output :
The following code ran successfully and redirect to the below page in browser to logged in to my Azure account.

I authenticated successfully after logged in as shown below.

I retrieved the access token using the authorization_code flow as shown below.


Thanks for your response. I had mentioned the same redirect url (i.e. localhost:1410) in my azure application and still I am getting the same error (local host refused to connect

If you still facing the same issue then, check this Docs to fix the issue.
